# Determine if page was loaded from history or from QR Code scan

Tags: qr-code, browser-history

Here's the situation. I am trying to implement a system in a restaurant where each table has its unique QR Code. The QR Code is fixed and hard printed on the table. My application is basically a web page and the QR Code is simply a web page address with an encrypted parameter which identifies the table.

This system is already protected (to a certain degree) from pranksters by only allowing orders to come from the IP address of the Wifi connection. So you need to be at least connected to the restaurant's wifi to use this page. Doesn't protect from people outside the building, but that is another issue.

The problem occurs if a user comes today and scans the code for table 3 and places an order. If the user comes later and sits at table 5, I don't know how to stop them from loading the previously scanned link (for table 3) and place an order for table 3.

Having constantly changing time stamped QR Codes would address the problem, but that is impossible since the QR codes are fixed.

Is there a way for the page to "know" that it has been loaded from a QR Code Scan, or whether it was loaded from the browsing history? We are talking about pages loaded on a smartphone, so I guess that complicates matters.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.  There's usually no "refer" header which will tell you that a page has been loaded from a bookmark or retrieved from a scanner's history rather than scanned directly.

Having an ever changing QR code is not impossible (using eInk or a small display) but that doesn't solve the problem.

Here's how I would fix it.

User scans a code - example.com/table3 - the first thing they see is a map with table 3 highlighted on it.

Text says "If you're not at table 3, please scan the code on your table. If you are - click here to order." Or something like that.

Explain to the user that if they're not sitting at the correct table - someone else will get their food!

Comment: Thanks. The problem is with pranksters ordering food for other tables on purpose. Since currently the setup does not feature payments with the orders, they got little to lose. However, I found another way around the problem. I set the QR code to point to an inexisting page which then (through error 404 handling) redirects to another page while also passing a dynamic time stamp (querystring). It is this second page that is being stored in the browser's history, and since it contains an encrypted time stamp, I can use that to see how long ago the QR code was scanned. Not perfect, but passable.